# When adding two large numbers in SAS, why are the results nonsensical?

Tags: sas

See below for for some example code:

```
PROC SQL noprint;
          CREATE TABLE check AS
    
                SELECT *, round(var1,1e16) + round(var2,1e16) as final
    
                FROM dir.A;
    
    QUIT; RUN;
```

The numbers I am adding are -3.0584695E31 and 3.058469E31 and I get a sum of 4.5035996E15 but in reality, the sum should be on the order of ~1000.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 1):

All numbers in SAS are [floating point values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) with a precision of about 16 ditits. This corresponds to ["double precision"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) in most programming languages and databases.

When calculating with values of around 1E31, you should expect an error of around 1E31/1E16, i.e. 1E15.

Comment: This is definitely helpful to know

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is, rather, round the *result*.  Rounding the intermediary steps is mostly irrelevant - you'll still have some fuzziness in the space between the two rounded numbers, unless it happens to be already a precise difference.  You may not see much difference in some cases, but in other cases you'll see a lot of difference (particularly when you expect, for example, the two numbers to sum to zero).

```
PROC SQL noprint;
      CREATE TABLE check AS

            SELECT *, round(var1+var2,1e16) as final

            FROM dir.A;

QUIT;
```